# Combine hdf5 checkpoint files

Tags: python, keras

Im using the following code to combine all hdf5 file generated by keras.

```
import h5py

output_file = h5py.File('output.h5', 'w')

#keep track of the total number of rows
total_rows = 0
import os

file_list = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

for n, f in enumerate(file_list):
  your_data = h5py.File(n, 'r+')
  total_rows = total_rows + your_data.shape[0]
  total_columns = your_data.shape[1]

  if n == 0:
    #first file; create the dummy dataset with no max shape
    create_dataset = output_file.create_dataset("Name", (total_rows, total_columns), maxshape=(None, None))
    #fill the first section of the dataset
    create_dataset[:,:] = your_data
    where_to_start_appending = total_rows

  else:
    #resize the dataset to accomodate the new data
    create_dataset.resize(total_rows, axis=0)
    create_dataset[where_to_start_appending:total_rows, :] = your_data
    where_to_start_appending = total_rows

output_file.close()
```

it is throwing the following error.

> expected str bytes or osPathLike objects.

why so? how can I be able to combine all hdf5 data sets from keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling a HDF5- File like a dataset.

```
f = h5py.File(n, 'r+')
your_data=f["Name_of_Dataset"] #open a dataset
total_rows = total_rows + your_data.shape[0]
```

If you don't know the name of the dataset you can get it as follows

```
Dataset_Names=f.keys()
```

You could also improve performance by setting a chunk size according to your access pattern. Now you have auto-chunking, which is enabled by default if you use a resizeable dataset.